# Swagger Error Not a valid response definition

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

I have a huge Json file that I'm analyzing with Swagger Editor.

It gives me an error message :

```
    Swagger Error

Not a valid response definition
Details
Object
code: "ONE_OF_MISSING"
params: Array [0]
message: "Not a valid response definition"
path: Array [5]
schemaId: "http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#"
inner: Array [2]
level: 900
type: "Swagger Error"
description: "Not a valid response definition"
lineNumber: -1
```

What I want to know is where I should look at.

What I understand : I should look at the "responses" part of my Json. Right ?

Maybe that's only an english issue, but I don't get one_of_missing. What does it mean.

The other errors I had were easy to understand cause it told me which line I had to look at, but what does lineNumber: -1 mean ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of your YAML file.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot publish my json but I'd be interested in understanding what these messages mean.

Comment: The error means your API definition has syntax errors. But the error is non-descriptive (and might be misleading), so it's hard to tell the exact cause without seeing your actual definition. By the way, you seem to be using the old editor v.2.x. Try the latest editor (3.x) at http://editor.swagger.io - it might provide more descriptive error messages. You can also try the online validator `http://online.swagger.io/validator/debug?url=<YOUR_URL>`.

Comment: Also check out [Describing Responses](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-responses/) and make sure your response matches the expected syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually changing my json into a yml helped a lot as it indicated me which line was wrong. There was a description missing somewhere.Thanks again.